# Is there a way in intellij to share android "logcat filters" without checking in the workspace.xml file?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

it would be nice to share android logcat filters used in intellij and not have to re-create them every time one checks out a new copy of a project.  They are stored in the .idea/workspace.xml file which should not be checked in for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to make them part of the "debug configurations" ???

Comment: Better later then never, i've created a feature request for JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-341098/Feature-Request-Share-android-logcat-filters-favourites-among-the-team

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for but I hope it may help anyway. If you use LogRabbit to view your Android logs you can export and share your filters easily.

To export a filter right click on the filter and select "export". To import just select file->open and select the filter to import.

You can find several filters to import from the LogRabbit website here http://lograbbit.com

Here is an example of creating filters: https://youtu.be/HeildKynnuc

I hope this helps.

Comment: can this be added to a build script :) so it saves automatically with every succesful build :)

Comment: No, sorry I did not realize you were looking for a build script solution.

Comment: No integrated in with intellij .idea folder the best an other solution is a workaround.  Basically something you can set and forget (and reset and forget) no cutting and pasting or other manual actions necessary.

Comment: It is a great idea. Now I want that too. +1 for your question.